# click event refresh my page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

so I try to trigger a filter method using the following button. But problem is that when I click it, it will automatic refresh my page. I fetch my needed data from my backend and store it in a local state after the render method. How can I prevent the reload caused by the button, so my filter method can works correctly? thanks!

fetching function(used after the render function):

```
  saveFetchedBeers = () =>{

        if(this.state.beers.length ===0 && this.props.beers.loading===false ){

            this.state.beers= [...this.props.beers.beer];

        }
     }
```

state of the component:

```
 state= {
        beers:[]

    }
```

input & button:

```
<input ref='searchByName' type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search"></input>
<button type="submit" onClick={() => this.getBeerByName('NL')} >Submit</button>
```

The click event function:

```
  getBeerByName = (input,e) =>{

         let newArray = this.state.beers.filter(function (el){
             return el.name===input;
         });

         this.state.beers = [...newArray];
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could you please try this :

first pass event with click :

```
<button type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.getBeerByName('NL',e)} >Submit</button>
```

then add `e.preventDefault()` like this

```
 getBeerByName = (input,e) =>{
     e.preventDefault()
     let newArray = this.state.beers.filter(function (el){
         return el.name===input;
     });

     this.state.beers = [...newArray];
 }
```

or change button type to `button` like this

```
 <button type="button" onClick={() => this.getBeerByName('NL')} >Submit</button>
```

without `e.preventDefault` in `getBeerByName`

Comment: I tried your solution. but I get an error, saying _TypeError: Cannot read property 'preventDefault' of undefined_ in getBeerByName.

Comment: @Dave_888 are you passing `e` also in `this.getBeerByName`

Comment: yup like u said. ` <button type="submit" onClick={(e) => this.getBeerByName('NL',e)} >Submit</button>`

Comment: oh yee it does work this way. how can type button works and submit not? thanks for the help!

Comment: @Dave_888 because as you see [in this link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/submit) submit raise event to user agent for form but button type not. if it help you please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps an

```
e.preventDefault();
```

somewhere at the end of `getBeerByName` would do what you like, but I'm not familiar with React, so you could give it a try.