# Fetch request makes unwanted page reload

Tags: javascript, node.js, ajax, rest, express

I am running into an issue with a fetch request from my client side to the server.
Somehow the fetch request is causing the page to reload, something I want to avoid. I have searched several places in order to figure this one out, but I have to turn to you guys for assistance.

All data transactions between the database is working as expected. Apparently there is no errors in the functionality. Except the fact that I do not want the page to reload on triggering the fetch request.

Note that I am using EJS as a template engine and Bootstrap 4 as a front-end library.

Please have a look at my code below. Any tips in order to avoid the page reload, is much appreciated.

**Front-end HTML:**

```
// detailjs.ejs

<div class="row">
    <form>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="UpdateArchiveStatus(this)" id="btn-move-to-inbox"><i class="fas fa-inbox"></i> Flytt til innboks</button>
        <button class="btn btn-outline-primary" onclick="UpdateArchiveStatus(this)" id="btn-move-to-archive"><i class="fas fa-archive"></i> Arkiver</button>
    </form>
</div>

<div class="row">
    <input type="hidden" name="resolved-status" id="resolved-status" value="<%= message.status.isResolved %>">
    <input type="hidden" name="archive-status" id="archive-status" value="<%= message.status.isArchived %>">
</div>

<!-- Script include --!>
<script src="/assets/js/messages/message-admin.js">
```

**Front-end JavaScript**

```
//message-admin.js

const UpdateArchiveStatus = btn => {
var messageId = $('#message-id').val();
var currentArchiveStatus = $('#archive-status').val();
var newArchiveStatus = null;

if (currentArchiveStatus == 'true') {
    newArchiveStatus = false;
 } else {
   newArchiveStatus = true;
 }
 StoreArchiveStatus(messageId, newArchiveStatus);
};

function StoreArchiveStatus (messageId, archiveStatus) {
    fetch(`/backoffice/api/messages/archive/${messageId}/${archiveStatus}`, 
    {
        method: 'GET',
    })
    .then(result => {
         return result.json();
    })
    .then(data => {
        $('#archive-status').val(data.status);
        CheckArchiveStatus();
        console.log(data.message);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err);
     });
    };

function ToggleArchivedInterface () {
    var inboxButton   = $('#btn-move-to-inbox');
    var archiveButton = $('#btn-move-to-archive');

    inboxButton.removeClass('invisible');
    archiveButton.addClass('invisible');
};

function ToggleInboxInterface () {
    var inboxButton   = $('#btn-move-to-inbox');
    var archiveButton = $('#btn-move-to-archive');

    archiveButton.removeClass('invisible');
    inboxButton.addClass('invisible');
};

async function CheckArchiveStatus () {
    var archiveStatus = $('#archive-status').val();
    if (archiveStatus == 'true') {
        ToggleArchivedInterface();
    } else {
        ToggleInboxInterface();
    }
};
```

**Back-end route:**

```
//routes/backoffice.js

router.get('/api/messages/archive/:messageId/:archiveStatus', authenticate, backofficeController.apiUpdateMessageArchiveStatus);
```

**Back-end controller function:**

```
//controllers/backoffice.js

exports.apiUpdateMessageResolvedStatus = (req, res, next) => {
    var messageId      = req.params.messageId;
    var resolvedStatus = req.params.resolvedStatus;

    VisitorMessage.findOneAndUpdate(
        { '_id' : messageId },
        { $set: {
            'status.isResolved': resolvedStatus
        }
    }).then((message) => {
        res.status(200).json({message: `Message status was changed`, status: resolvedStatus})
   }).catch((err) => {
       console.log('The following error occured during update:\n' + err);
       res.status(500).json({message: 'An error occured during update.'});
   })
};
```

Comment: fetch requests don't cause page reloads.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [click event refresh my page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50516791/click-event-refresh-my-page)

Comment: Yeah, pretty sure since the button is in a form, it's defaulting to a submission.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The problem is that when your button is clicked, the form is submitting and causing the page to reload.

You can see the problem in action [here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MxJzLz).

```
function btnclick(e) {
  // comment and uncomment e.preventDefault to see the differences
  e.preventDefault()
}
```

Prevent the default event action and the problem will be solved.

Comment: Thank you, Michel. I marked your answer as solution. It's a bit different approach then the other suggestion, but it did the trick as well.

Comment: Jeez, why is this downvoted?  It's exactly correct.

Comment: I've faced the same issue and instead of preventing default, I would rather recommend to reevaluate if you need form at all. 

I've just replaces form with div in my case.

Answer (score 0):

As commented by SpeedOfRound, he is quite right. I did not see this issue myself. Thank you for the help!

**Solution:**
Remove redundant `<form>` tags in the `detailjs.ejs` file. These tags caused the page to refresh itself, even though I was using a fetch request.

Comment: I currently have the same or similar problem even though I am not using any FORM-tags.  Thank you for your question and answer, it at least is giving me a clue and direction to look into.